# Angular Library module not found when consuming locally in JHipster

Tags: angular, jhipster, angular-library

I'm trying to make reusable login component in my Jhipster application, so I created Angular library in order to achieve this. With that, we can use this login component in the other our applications as well.

I also included the necessarry services that the component depends on.

**1-** I created the library with `ng generate library login-lib`

**2-** When the library is created I also put the services as well.
So the file structure looks like this;
[image: library structure]

**3-** I exported all the files in the `public-api.ts`

```
export { LoginLibService } from './lib/login-lib.service';
export { LoginLibComponent } from './lib/login-lib.component';
export { LoginLibModule } from './lib/login-lib.module';
export { Login } from './lib/login-lib.model';
export { Account } from './lib/auth/account-lib.model';
export { AccountService } from './lib/auth/account-lib.service';
export { AuthServerProvider } from './lib/auth/auth-jwt-lib.service';
export { StateStorageService } from './lib/auth/state-storage-lib.service';
export { UserRouteAccessLibService } from './lib/auth/user-route-access-lib.service';
export { ApplicationConfigService } from './lib/config/application-config-lib.service';
```

**4-** When i build the library using `ng build login-lib`, the compiled files goes under the root directory called `dist\login-lib`

**5-** Now i want to consume the `login-lib.component.ts` in order to render the template in the main application. Because there i have the login form.

**6-** I imported the `LoginLibModule` in the `login.module` inside of the application.

```
import { LoginLibModule } from '../../../../../dist/login-lib/public-api';

@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule, RouterModule.forChild([LOGIN_ROUTE]), LoginLibModule],
  declarations: [LoginWrapperComponent],
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

**7-** Later in the `LoginWrapperComponent` template, I'm rendering the `login-lib.component.ts` with `jhi-login-lib`.

---

**Now the problem;**

```
./src/main/webapp/app/login/login.module.ts:3:0-84 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../dist/login-lib/lib/login-lib.module' in 'C:\daten\dev\...\...\src\main\webapp\app\login'
```

I have the same error, whenever I'm trying to access the library from the `dist` rather than `projects\login-lib`. If i consume the files from source code of the library which is the `projects\login-lib`, i do not have any problem. Yet it was my fault that, I integrated library to the application using `projects\login-lib`.

**1-** No matter what the imported path, it does not recognized the module.
I've tried using,

```
import { LoginLibModule } from 'login-lib';,

import { LoginLibModule } from '../../../../../dist/login-lib/login-lib';,

import { LoginLibModule } from '../../../../../dist/login-lib/lib/login-lib.module';

import { LoginLibModule } from '../../../../../dist/login-lib/public-api';
```

**2-** I've tried to import the script file in my `angular.json` file in the library and the application;

```
"scripts": ["./dist/login-lib/fesm2015/login-lib.js"]
```

We are using another library and we imported to the script like this as well.

**3-** I've tried to build the `dist` to the path of `node_modules` as well. Still the same.

**4-** I've tried to publish to the `npm`, still the same error.

Comment: `dist` as part of a path in source code is always an error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that, when using JHipster, the built angular library will not work due to conflicts in the `tsconfig.file`.

The best practice is to consume the source files of the library until the integration of library is okay (means that use the projects folder files), later create a standalone angular application and pass the library in there (to use dist folder files). After that it can be published in `npm` and install like a normal package.

Because when the applications are build, `outDir` of the JHipster is **./target**, and Angular standalone application is **./dist**. So, in the JHipster application, no mather what it will not understand the outcome of the **./dist** folder.